# Push array to a collection of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to push an array to a collection of arrays but I'm getting unexpected results.

```
var itemX = ['a','b','c'];
var itemY = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
var itemList = [];

itemList.push(itemX);
itemList.push(itemY);
```

I'm expecting to get this:

```
itemList = [
       ['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['x', 'y', 'z']
]
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
itemList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Am I missing anything here?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: And I'm getting correct result

Comment: your code should work fine, please share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is working fine, probable reason is you might be trying to `alert itemList;` which alerts `a,b,c,x,y,z`.

```js
var itemX = ['a','b','c'];
var itemY = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
var itemList = [];

itemList.push(itemX);
itemList.push(itemY);

alert(JSON.stringify(itemList));
```

Comment: Yes indeed I am trying to alert itemlist.

Using `alert(JSON.stringify(itemList));`  displayed 
`['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']`

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(itemList));` displayed the result I wanted. Thank you.